# React, styled-components, typescript errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-banach-p27he?file=/src/card.tsx)

I'm using styled-components in a React app.

I wanted to structure the naming with a BEM like structure.

I'm using the examples in the article - https://tech.decisiv.com/structuring-our-styled-components-part-i-2bf21fa64b28

I also wanted to use typescript which is where I'm getting my errors

My demo works but I have errors that are the same as my actual app but there the app fails to load.

The errors are in App.tsx `<Card.header>Header</Card.header>`

```
JSX element type 'Card.header' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604)
```

and in card.tsx `Card.header = Header;`

```
Type 'StyledComponent<"h1", any, {}, never>' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
```

I have looked into these errors but can't find solution.

Does anyone know I how I might be able to fix these errors.

Comment: Just wondering, what exactly `Card.header = Header;` is this supposed to achieve..? What do you want to achieve? Some kinda inheritance pattern?

Comment: Please check the demo here https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sutherland-n4vb7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you assign another element in `Card` and you have created `Card` with `StyledComponent`.

You can fix your code in the following way,

```
        import styled from "styled-components";

        import Header from "./header";

        const Card: any = styled.div`
           border: 10px solid green;
           padding: 10px;
        `;

        Card.header = Header;

        export default Card;
```

for more details please check this [link](https://dev.to/sandro_roth/how-to-structure-styled-components-with-react-and-ts-27pn) and [demo here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-sutherland-n4vb7).

Other ways are to create an Interface in TypeScript can be used to define a type.

Please see following code for same,

```
        import styled, { StyledComponentBase } from "styled-components";
        import Header from "./header";

        interface ICard extends StyledComponentBase<any, {}> {
           header?: any;
        }

        const Card: ICard = styled.div`
            border: 10px solid green;
            padding: 10px;
        `;

        Card.header = Header;

        export default Card;
```

Please check the demo for this example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-grothendieck-y4085).

Hope this will help you.